# Updating a TextArea via setText clears all text

Tags: java

I made a chatroom, server and client, in java.

Here is the code were my onlinelist messes up:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            String message = din.readUTF();
            if (message.startsWith("CONNECTEDLISTEDWOOOOOOOOT")) {
                ConnectedList con = new ConnectedList();
                if (demanded == 1) {
                    con.ta.setText(message.substring(26));
                    con.setSize(200, 400);
                    con.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    con.setVisible(true);
                    demanded = 0;
                } else {
                    con.ta.setText(message.substring(26));
                }
            } else {
                ta.append(message+"\n");
                if(!lol.isActive()) {
                    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("bleep.wav");
                    AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in);         
                    AudioPlayer.player.start(as);   
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException ie) { System.out.println(ie); }
}
```

this block of code works perfectly:

```
if (demanded == 1) {
        con.ta.setText(message.substring(26));
        con.setSize(200, 400);
        con.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        con.setVisible(true);
        demanded = 0;
}
```

It creates a new window using JFrame just with a textlabel(ta) with all connected users on it, also demanded just controls wether the frame is already opened or not.

Then the part were it gets messed up:

```
 else {
      con.ta.setText(message.substring(26));
 }
```

Here it's just supposed to refresh the list by setting the text to the new list
but instead of doing that, it just wipes the window.

How can I fix it?

### Before:

[image]

### After:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should edit the question to include some screen shots to help clarify "it just wipes the window".

Comment: I will, just wait a few min :p

Comment: Looks like a nullpointer exception or that message isn't 26 chars long and yields into a indexoutofbounds exception

Comment: The message is longer, already tested it with System.out.println(message); and the message.substring(26)

Comment: Try and come up with a proper title for your question.  Noone's going to read about "just something weird which I don't see the problem in".

Comment: well apearently my creativity isn't good enough to find a fitting title :s

Comment: @Nicky: Have you tried stepping through that area with a debugger? Perhaps it is being called an extra time with an empty `message`.

Comment: well debug main project in netbeans doesn't tell me anything :s also, thanks for changing the title but i was using TextArea, not JTextArea and i'm very sure that it's not being send an extra time

Comment: You say that you tested it with `System.out.println(message)`. Could you try testing it with `System.out.println("The message is: \"" + message + "\"")`. In the first example, an empty `message` could be written to output without you noticing.

Comment: well, I just found out the problem

just putting: ConnectedList con = new ConnectedList(); at the top by all other variables,
now it does work,

thanks everyone for trying to help :D

Comment: +1 for improving the question. Also consider writing your answer and marking it as accepted.

Comment: @oksayt i wanted to do that but i had to wait another 6 hours before i could do that, and now i have to wait another 2 days to accept it... this site has some serious bad timings o.O

Answer (score 0):

well, I just found out the problem just putting: 
ConnectedList con = new ConnectedList(); 
at the top by all other variables, and now it does work,